# Django 1.10 single widget type for all ModelForm fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I have a `ModelForm`, which is composed from `Model`, with huge amount of columns with very different data types. However, I need to make `ModelForm` whose all mentioned fields in `ModelForm` have the same widget type (for example, checkbox, but it may be textarea, or whatever..).

**ModelForm**:

```
class EntertainerCheckboxForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Entertainer
        fields = ['first_name', 'second_name','last_name', ...]
        widgets = {
            'first_name': CheckboxInput(),
            'second_name': CheckboxInput(),
            'last_name': CheckboxInput()
            ...
        }
```

Is there any simple generic solution for this?

Comment: The accepted answer with a little bit of modification would allow for that on your project. It just loops over all the fields in `fields` and adds it to `widgets`. If that's not working then you may have a different problem.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you are asking about Y. If this is the case, you may get eve better solutions by updating the question with a broader context.

Comment: Guys, try it yourself... __init__ is not working because I need to add widgets property to Meta subclass, not into outer ModelForm.